# Pass proto field which has value only

Tags: node.js, grpc, protobuf.js

I have a service to pass input array of object to server using protobuf and successfully receive it on the server. The problem is I got the response according to the response definition. Here is the response

```
[ { uuid: '',
    quantity: 3,
    procurement_detail_uuid: '',
    distribution_officer_uuid: '',
    substore_uuid: '2343423443423' },
  { uuid: '',
    quantity: 3,
    procurement_detail_uuid: '',
    distribution_officer_uuid: '',
    substore_uuid: '676767' } ]
```

and here is the definition of the input

```
message ProcurementStockDistributionUpsertReqInput {
  string uuid = 1;
  int32 quantity = 2;
  string procurement_detail_uuid = 3;
  string distribution_officer_uuid = 4;
  string substore_uuid = 5;
}
```

as you can see some of the fields are empty. I thought about using [oneof](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto#oneof)

> If you have a message with many optional fields and where at most one
>   field will be set at the same time, you can enforce this behavior and
>   save memory by using the oneof feature.

I thought `oneof` is the right way to optionally pass fields which has value but hit the error. Then I rollback my code like this

```
service Procurement {
  rpc distributeUpsert (ProcurementStockDistributionUpsertReq) returns (ProcurementStockDistributionRes) {}
}

message ProcurementStockDistributionUpsertReq {
  message ProcurementStockDistributionUpsertReqInput {
    string uuid = 1;
    int32 quantity = 2;
    string procurement_detail_uuid = 3;
    string distribution_officer_uuid = 4;
    string substore_uuid = 5;
  }
  repeated ProcurementStockDistributionUpsertReqInput stocks = 1;
}
```

How to pre-omit those empty fields in proto